# Disable authentication for some methods

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

when I include the following dependency Spring asks for authentication for all rest requests.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

My UserController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserService us;

    @RequestMapping("/all")
    public Hashtable<String, User> getAll() {
        return us.getAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping("{id}")
    public User getPerson(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        return us.getPerson(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void registerNewUser() {
        us.registerNewUser();
    }
}
```

How can I disable authentication for the `registerNewUser()` method? It's for registering a user and I don't want any authentication for that method.

Answer (score 2):

You need a security configuration class and from there you can explicitly restrict that behaviour. For example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
        .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/users/**").authenticated()
          .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users").permitAll();  
  }
}
```

Comment: I created this class under the package org.springframework.security.samples.config but in the response body I still get Unauthorized

Comment: Can you make sure that the configuration is properly scanned by your application and wired in? It should be logged.

Comment: There is no mention of "SecurityConfig" in the logs when Spring boot starts. I also tried adding the @Autowired above the configure method